# What do I need to Connect XCODE development to SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql, ios, xcode, azure, odbc

I have an existing SQL Azure database with front ends ranging from .NET to MS-Access 2010.
For an Access user I only need an sqlncli driver plus Access runtime, an open firewall and a standard ODBC connection string. I am now developing an additional iPhone-based component and need suitable framework/api to make connection. What can I use?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to have your iPhone clients connect directly to SQL Azure. This means you would need to open the SQL Azure firewall for all these clients and you would also need the SQL Azure credentials on each device.

And you just don't want to make mobile apps dependent of a database. You want to be flexible, allowing you to change your database without impacting your client applications. In a controlled environment this 'could' be acceptable, but with mobile applications you can't count on updates being done right away on all devices.

That's why I would suggest on creating an API between your iPhone applications and your backend (SQL Azure or whatever). This is very easy to do using the [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and this has 2 advantages:

- Your iPhone application would connect to your API using JSON for example. Nothing special here, this is something standard for iOS applications.
- Your ASP.NET Web API application can simply use Entity Framework or SqlConnection/SqlCommand to connect to SQL Azure. Again pretty standard stuff, no need for special hacks.

And since you use standard implementations on both sides, you'll be able to find plenty of doucmentation on the internet.

These links can get you started:

- [Making JSON Web APIs with ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta and ASP.NET Web API](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)
- [Developing RESTful iOS Apps with RestKit](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service (`WCF` Service would be best) and communicate with it. You can't connect directly to the `SQL Server` and even if you can that's a very very bad idea and it's totally insecure.